# How do I apply the binary cross-entropy element-wise and then sum all these losses in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function, cross-entropy

I want to write a function with two arguments, `A` and `B`, tensors of the same shape (for example, `13x13`, or some other shape), and that returns a number that represents the summation of all losses when applied binary cross-entropy componentwise. So, for `A[i, j]` and `B[i, j]` we find the binary cross-entropy loss, and then sum over all `i` and `j`. How to implement that in Keras and Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily define this function using the backend functions [`sum`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/f9210387088fe91b5bc8999cf0cb41a0fe9eacf6/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L1268) and [`binary_crossentropy`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/f9210387088fe91b5bc8999cf0cb41a0fe9eacf6/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3290) (or use their equivalents in Tensorflow directly):

```
def func(A, B):
    return K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(A,B))
```

Note that `K.binary_crossentropy()` assumes that the given input values are probabilities; if that's not the case then pass `from_logit=True` as another argument to it.

Further, if you would like to use this function in a [`Lambda`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer, then you need to change it so that it accepts a list of tensors as input:

```
def func(inp):
    return K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(inp[0], inp[1]), [1,2]) # take the sum for each sample independently

# ...
out = Lambda(func)([A, B])
```

As you can see, `[1,2]` has been passed to `K.sum()` as its `axis` argument to take the sum over all the element of a single sample (and not over the whole batch).

Answer (score 1):

The solution suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52555557/3924118) may actually not be what you (reader) are looking for.

If `A` and `B` are `NxM`, where `M > 1`, then `binary_crossentropy(A, B)` will not compute the binary cross-entropy element-wise, but `binary_crossentropy(A, B)` returns an array of shape `Nx1`, where `binary_crossentropy(A, B)[i]` correspond to the average binary cross-entropy between `A[i]` and `B[i]` (i.e. it computes the binary cross-entropy between `A[i][j]` and `B[i][j]`, for all `j`, then it computes the average of the `M` binary cross-entropies).

If you want to calculate the binary cross-entropy between the element `A(i, j)` and `B(i, j)`, for all `i` and `j`, then you may first want to reshape `A` and `B`, so that they have the shape `(N*M)x1`.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.random.rand(4, 2).reshape((-1, 1))
b = np.random.rand(4, 2).reshape((-1, 1))
print("ce between a[i, j] and b[i, j]) =", tf.losses.binary_crossentropy(a, b))
print("average cross-entropy =", np.mean(tf.losses.binary_crossentropy(a, b)))
```

However, if you want to compute the binary cross-entropy between `A` and `B` element-wise and take the average of all the binary cross-entropies, then you do not need to reshape `A` and `B`. So, if `A` and `B` are `NxM` arrays, then `binary_crossentropy(A, B)` produces an `Nx1` array, where each element corresponds to the average binary cross-entropy between row `i` of `A` and row `i` of `B` (for `i=1, ..., N`). Finally, to take the average of all binary cross-entropies, we also need to take the average of `binary_crossentropy(A, B)`, i.e. `tf.reduce_mean(binary_crossentropy(A, B))`.